# Cannot pass the consent page

Tags: java, autodesk-forge

We have a java application that is trying to connect to autodesk to display user models. 
To login, I created an embedded Browser that opens 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authorize?response_type=code&client_id.... '
when login page is opened properly and I can enter the password no problem, but when I get to the authorize application page and click allow, nothing happens. I was expecting to get to the next page (that has the code in the url) but nothing happens. any idea what is wrong ?

Comment: Do you handle redirects correctly in your app?

Answer (score 0):

Try looks at what exactly happened immediately after the redirect first:

- Examine your browser's network (can use built-in dev tools) after you hit `allow`
- Check the browser’s console for errors while you are on the login page
- Try redirect to a robust, third party test trap (e.g. ngrok) to isolate the issue

If nothing works add me (bryan.huang at autodesk dot com) to your app so we can triage together.